# TYPO3 v4.6 about IRRE (sorting)

Tags: content-management-system, typo3

We must update the field data sorting `sorting`.

I set `$TCA['tx_table2']['ctrl']['sortby'] = 'sorting';`

And i set:

```
$TCA['tx_table1']['columns']['uid_records'] = array(
            ............        
            'config' => array(
                'type' => 'inline',
                'languageMode' => 'inherit',
                'foreign_table' => 'tx_table2',
                'foreign_sortby' => 'sorting',
                'size' => 1,
                'minitems' => 0,
                'maxitems' => 100,
            )
);
```

But when moving the recording position, the data field `sorting` is not updated.
Values are recorded only when creating a new record.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Is it possible that both table tx_table1 and tx_table2 has a field with name sorting? Because it could lead to problems. Or is it only for tx_table2 defined?

Comment: Yes. Table `tx_table1` and `tx_table2` has a fild with name sorting. Is this a problem? But in TCA tables fild sorting not defined and not have configurations.

Comment: Try to delete the sort_by option for tx_table1 = $TCA['tx_table2']['ctrl']['sortby'] should be not set. I have read an old e-mail, where that was the problem.

Comment: You mean `$TCA['tx_table1']['ctrl']['sortby']`  remove?

Comment: Yes, see here: http://lists.typo3.org/pipermail/typo3-project-irre/2007-September/000235.html